# Disable multi cursor functionality

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not like the Visual Studio multi cursor options, and I never use them.

Inevitably, I phantom-pressing some key combination that brings up a multi cursor option, then I write some code, and then the code is destroyed afterward. Please tell me how to completely disable all such functionality in Visual Studio Code. I am running on Ubuntu, but also interested in how to accomplish this on Windows (if there is any difference).

I should mention, that this happens literally once every 5 minutes to me on Ubuntu, but in Windows it happens much less frequently (like once an hour).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove the keyboard shortcut(s) that trigger this functionality.

Click on the gear on the bottom-left corner of the window and choose "Keyboard Shortcuts" from the menu. Type "Add Cursor" into the "Search" box and it shows only the commands that contain "Add Cursor" in their name.

Right-click on each command that add a cursor and has a keyboard shortcut associated and select "Remove Keybinding".

Also search for "Multi-Cursor". It could return the command "Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier" that is associated to a combination of modifier keys (one or more of `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift`). If such a combination of keys is pressed when you click in the editor window it adds a new text cursor at the click position. You should also removed these key bindings.

Comment: I just implemented this. Let me try this for about an hour and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Hmm. I think perhaps my mouse is broken. This seemed to help a little bit, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Wow. It seems that this was something related to the mouse. I was using a Razor Deathadder mouse. Perhaps it is defective or something, because I switched to a Logitech mouse, and the problem went away. Nonetheless, this answer was helpful

Answer (score 33):

[image: Switch Coulmn selection mode]

Un-check Selection->Column Selection Mode

Answer (score 2):

Set this settings in editor settings :

"editor.columnSelection": false,

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio :

[image]

Un-check Selection->Column Selection Mode